# How to write old VB Commands in Powershell

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I want to write some old VB into PS, however there are some old DOS commands here that I am struggling to write into powershell. For instance, I want to delete files from an Archive, and the way its written in VB is:

```
 command=(%comspec% /C DEL C:\\MyFile.txt",0,True)


    If result <> 0 then
        txtFile.writeline "ERROR"
        txtFile.writeline "File does not exist.."
        result = 0
    Else    
        txtFile.writeline "Success"     
   End if
```

In Powershell, The /C DEL is the line I'm having trouble writing. How would I write this command in powershell or would I just ignore it completely and just carry on with my IF statement?

Thanks,

Comment: I would use `Remove-Item` to delete a file.  Calling `cmd.exe` to do it would be bad practice.  The rest of your question is pretty basic stuff that suggests you should read up on the language syntax some.

Comment: Also, there's no "DOS" involved here. (Cmd.exe has nothing to do with DOS.)

Comment: You received a good answer from VertigoRay. I *strongly* recommend that, as you're converting VBScript to Powershell, you do *not* attempt to do a simple one-for-one translation of the syntax. Instead, understand *what* the VBScript is doing and instead write idiomatic PowerShell (use the right cmdlets, syntax, style, etc.) rather than produce sub-optimal code which perpetuates potentially misguided VBScript (the script you've posted here is not how I would have recommended doing it in VBScript to begin with, for example - it looks like a translation of batch instead of writing clean VBS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In powershell, just use `Remove-Item`. This mimics your VB pretty well:

```
try {
    Remove-Item 'C:\MyFile.txt' -Force -ErrorAction 'Stop'
    Write-Host 'Success'
} catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException] {
    Write-Host 'ERROR'
    Write-Host 'File does not exist..'
}
```

Of course, there's a dozen ways this cat can be skinned:

```
if (Test-Path 'C:\MyFile.txt') {
    Remove-Item 'C:\MyFile.txt' -Force
    Write-Host 'Success'
} else {
    Write-Host 'ERROR'
    Write-Host 'File does not exist..'
}
```

There's definitely more options out there ...